# Method call after register of accounts-ui in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using accounts-ui for login and registration in MeteorJS.

I want to add a role,on every newly registered user.
I am using onCreateUser but it is throwing error 
*Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error:insert requires an argument*
Here is, what i am trying..

```
  Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(user._id, ["Student"]);
        return user;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I use this code for adding default roles:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile) {
    user.profile = options.profile;
  }
  user.roles = ['student'];
  return user;
});
```

Comment: is it right way?
and is it compatible with alanning-roles module of meteor.

Comment: Sure, all that Roles.addUsersToRoles(user._id, ["Student"]); does is that it adds roles property with value ['Student']. You can try it.